# qt autocomplete prompt not showing pointers of my class

Tags: qt, qt-creator

The problem is that autocomplete prompt not showing name of my class pointer.

Fragment of my code

```
  QFile ingredFile;
    if(loadFileWithDirection(&ingredFile, qApp->applicationDirPath() + MENUINXML + INGREDIENTSFILE ))
    {
        QXmlStreamReader *xmlStream = new QXmlStreamReader(&ingredFile);

        while(!xmlStream->atEnd() && !xmlStream->hasError())
        {
                QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlStream->readNext();
                if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument) {
                        continue;
                }
                if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
                {

                        if(xmlStream->name() == "id")
                        {
                                continue;
                        }
                       
                        Ingredient *ingredient = new Ingredient();    
                        // when I'm typing ingre I can see prompt with 
                        // class Ingredient, ingredFile (which is 
                        //  declared  above) but is lack of ingredient 
                        // pointer
```

If I change code to:

```
Ingredient ingredient;
// now when I'm typing ingre I can see 
// ingredient on the list of autocomplete prompt
```

I tried to build project and run it, but it doesn't change anything.
What is more strange when I type `xml` it shows `xmlStream` on the list of prompt  and this is the pointer.

What is reason of this behavior ?

Did you had problems like this with qt?

UPDATED

I'm using qt Creator, version:

> Qt Creator 3.2.2 (opensource)
>
> Based on Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using qt creator, but I don't remember right now which version. I will update question at the evening.